# Pass in different properties for binding for the code that has some "templates"

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <sfChart:RangeControlVisibilityConverter x:Key="RangeControlVisibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="X Control" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Minimum" Visibility="{Binding XRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding XRangeMinimum}" Visibility="{Binding XRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"
                                      MinValue="{Binding XAbsoluteMin}" MaxValue="{Binding XAbsoluteMax}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Maximum" Visibility="{Binding XRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding XRangeMaximum}"  Visibility="{Binding XRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"
                                      MinValue="{Binding XAbsoluteMin}" MaxValue="{Binding XAbsoluteMax}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <GroupBox Header="Y Control" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Minimum" Visibility="{Binding YRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding XRangeMinimum}" Visibility="{Binding YRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"
                                      MinValue="{Binding YAbsoluteMin}" MaxValue="{Binding YAbsoluteMax}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Maximum" Visibility="{Binding YRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding YRangeMaximum}"  Visibility="{Binding YRangeControl, Converter={StaticResource RangeControlVisibilityConverter}}"
                                      MinValue="{Binding YAbsoluteMin}" MaxValue="{Binding YAbsoluteMax}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Notice how similar the X and Y portion are? They are identical, except that some properties are appropriately swapped depending on whether it's X or Y.

I feel like the above structure can be refactored and duplicated code removed, **preferably using Control Template**. How to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol

Comment: I prefer to use Control Template, question updated.

Comment: You would obviously have to write some kind of derived control, e.g. a derived GroupBox with an appropriate ControlTemplate. You would have to declare some properties somewhere. Or you define a set of attached properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get rid of the duplication because those are literally two independent contents/data displayed by two GroupBox elements.
All you can do is to refactor your data structures to enable `DataTemplates`.
For example, you can define a data model to represent the information for "x" and "y" by introducing a new type e.g. `DataModel`.
Then create a `DataTemplate` and a content host that will present the `DataModel` using the `DataTemplate`:

**DataModel.cs**

```cs
class Datamodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public double AbsoluteMin { get; }
  public double AbsoluteMax { get; }
}
```

**Data.cs**

```cs
class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Title { get; }
  public DataModel X { get; }
  public DataModel Y { get; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // A dependency property
  public Data DataItem { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
 
    this.DataItem = new Data()
    {
      X = new DataModel() { Title = "X Control", AbsoluteMin = 10, AbsoluteMax = 100 },
      Y = new DataModel() { Title = "Y Control", AbsoluteMin = 10, AbsoluteMax = 100 } 
    };
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="VisualRoot">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="DataModel">
      <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}">
        <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox MinValue="{Binding AbsoluteMin}"
                                  MaxValue="{Binding AbsoluteMax}" />
      </GroupBox>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- The content hosts -->

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=VisualRoot, Path=DataItem.X}" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=VisualRoot, Path=DataItem.Y}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```